# Find parent() of control, then find("a") JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<td>` that looks something like this:

```
<td class="myTDClass">
    <span class="spanClass">Header</span>
    <br />
    <img class='myImages' style='cursor: hand;' onclick='doSomething(control)' alt='this is my alt Text'></img>
    <br />
    <span style="color: #123456;">More Text</span>
    <br />
    <a class='findThisClass'>Insert Alt Text Here</a>
</td>
```

This calls some jQuery code that sets the alt tag to some new text. Then, i want it to set the `<a>` element to some new text. Here is the jQuery code:

```
doSomething = function(control)
  {
    var $myControl = $(control);
    $myControl.attr("alt", "This is the new Alt Text!");

    var $newControl = $(control).parent().siblings().find(".findThisClass").first();
    alert($newControl.find("a").text());
  });
```

The jQuery code sets the alt tag great, but doesn't find the `<a class=findThisClass />`.

I think I'm using the `.parent()` and `.siblings()` wrong. Can anyone find my error? The idea here is that I can search *just* inside the `<td>` for the `<a>` element, and not touch the other  elements in other `<td>`s

Comment: Why do you need the `.parent()`? The `<a>` is a sibling of the `<img>`. Try taking `parent()` out of `$newControl` and see what happens.

Comment: `cursor: hand;`?  Do you mean `cursor: pointer;`?

Comment: @Rocket `cursor: hand` was a special cursor style for MSIE somewhere =< 6.

Comment: BTW, what is `control` as an argument for `doSomething` in `onclick`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var $newControl = $(control).closest('.myTDClass').find(".findThisClass");
alert($newControl.text());
```

Also `img` is self closing tag, instead of:

```
<img></img>
```

Just use:

```
<img... />
```

And instead of:

```
onclick='doSomething(control)'
```

Use:

```
onclick='doSomething(this)'
```

so that jQuery has really a control to work with :)

### [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/ebawow)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to find the `<a>` that's in the same table cell as your `<img>`, you don't need to use `parent()`. All you need to do is call `.siblings` Try:

```
var $newControl = $(control).siblings('a.findThisClass').first();
```

This assumes `control` points to the image within the table cell.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a.findThisClass", $myControl).first()
```

Answer (score 2):

`a` is a sibling of the image, so, simply:

```
$(control).siblings(".findThisClass")
```